# How to insert html code block directly to pug

Tags: javascript, html, pug

After revising my code, I want to insert a code block directly to my pug file. Is there any way I can do it?

Here is the html code:

```
        <!-- start Mixpanel -->
        <script type="text/javascript">(function(c,a){if(!a.__SV){var b=window;try{var d,m,j,k=b.location,f=k.hash;d=function(a,b){return(m=a.match(RegExp(b+"=([^&]*)")))?m[1]:null};f&&d(f,"state")&&(j=JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(d(f,"state"))),"mpeditor"===j.action&&(b.sessionStorage.setItem("_mpcehash",f),history.replaceState(j.desiredHash||"",c.title,k.pathname+k.search)))}catch(n){}var l,h;window.mixpanel=a;a._i=[];a.init=function(b,d,g){function c(b,i){var a=i.split(".");2==a.length&&(b=b[a[0]],i=a[1]);b[i]=function(){b.push([i].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,
0)))}}var e=a;"undefined"!==typeof g?e=a[g]=[]:g="mixpanel";e.people=e.people||[];e.toString=function(b){var a="mixpanel";"mixpanel"!==g&&(a+="."+g);b||(a+=" (stub)");return a};e.people.toString=function(){return e.toString(1)+".people (stub)"};l="disable time_event track track_pageview track_links track_forms track_with_groups add_group set_group remove_group register register_once alias unregister identify name_tag set_config reset opt_in_tracking opt_out_tracking has_opted_in_tracking has_opted_out_tracking clear_opt_in_out_tracking people.set people.set_once people.unset people.increment people.append people.union people.track_charge people.clear_charges people.delete_user people.remove".split(" ");
for(h=0;h<l.length;h++)c(e,l[h]);var f="set set_once union unset remove delete".split(" ");e.get_group=function(){function a(c){b[c]=function(){call2_args=arguments;call2=[c].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(call2_args,0));e.push([d,call2])}}for(var b={},d=["get_group"].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,0)),c=0;c<f.length;c++)a(f[c]);return b};a._i.push([b,d,g])};a.__SV=1.2;b=c.createElement("script");b.type="text/javascript";b.async=!0;b.src="undefined"!==typeof MIXPANEL_CUSTOM_LIB_URL?
MIXPANEL_CUSTOM_LIB_URL:"file:"===c.location.protocol&&"//cdn4.mxpnl.com/libs/mixpanel-2-latest.min.js".match(/^\/\//)?"https://cdn4.mxpnl.com/libs/mixpanel-2-latest.min.js":"//cdn4.mxpnl.com/libs/mixpanel-2-latest.min.js";d=c.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];d.parentNode.insertBefore(b,d)}})(document,window.mixpanel||[]);
mixpanel.init("e55528b9a14d805d969f71532bdb9d36");</script><!-- end Mixpanel -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            mixpanel.track("Button Click");
        </script>
```

Here is the Pug file, which is the target

```
doctype html
head
  title testFile
  script(type="text/jaascript").
    if(foo) bar(1+5)
body
  h1 need some help!
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can do it - including HTML as text in a Pug/Jade file will parse into Pug:

```
body
  | <script>...</script>
```

That character `|` is a pipe character, not a lowercase L `l` or an uppercase i `I`. On most keyboards it's made by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd> (the button below <kbd>Delete</kbd>/<kbd>Backspace</kbd>).